# How to make an ionic application run with ui-router

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I try to create an ionic application and I want to add functionality to buttons by linking HTML pages using AngularJS. How can I do that ? I have linked a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xC9P46CC5NiN2xrMP6vZ?p=preview).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"/>
  <title>Ionic Framework Example</title>
  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <div class="bar bar-header">
    <h1 class="title">Multi Page Application</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="bar bar-subheader">
    <h2 class="title">Sub Header</h2>
    <div class="button-bar bar-balanced">
      <a class="button">First page </a>
      <a class="button">Second page </a>
      <a class="button">Third page</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ion-content></ion-content>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: link what is the use of ui-view

Comment: https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/